# RGB565 font table in C Array values

Tags: fonts, rgb

I am using the Monochrome display. In this, displayed the bitmapped fonts, i.e. 1 bit per pixel. It is working fine.

Now, for the same monochrome display, the other driver takes the RGB565 format as input values, i.e. 16 bits per pixel and convert this to single bit and write to the display.

Need the RGB565 format font table as C array or some Linux utility to produce the RGB565 format fonts, so we can send this to driver inputs.

Need some images as RGB565 format or need some utility to create the RGB565 format images and send this as input to drivers and test this.

Comment: you must show us your code, before getting any help from us.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Take a [tour] and learn [ask]. Provide details about your question, show us what did you already searched/tried.